# Stuck or dead pixels on ipad 1st generation

Tags: display

I have an ipad 1st generation that has a strip going across the screen about half way down. It's in the area where the icon shows up when you set the volume. It runs completely across the screen and is about 2 inches wide. It stays grey/black most of the time. But if you try to watch a movie on the ipad it changes to all different colors. I've been told that its either stuck or dead pixels. If that is the case, is there a fix for this? Would a new digitizer help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Since that would be almost 200,000 pixels, I do not think they are dead or stuck, at least not in the traditional sense. I'd say there is something else that's broken.